# Boot automatically into bootloader?

Tags: bootloader, bios

I have 2 hard drives. 1 hard drive with Ubuntu, the other with Windows 7.

My question: Is it possible to let the bios ask me every boot via bootloader which hard drive I would like to boot WITHOUT pressing any button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If You have grub on the Ubuntu hard drive, and boot from there, it can ask You, which operation system you want to load.
Just set the BIOS boot order, to boot from this drive.